# Python / Seaborn - How to plot the names of each value in a scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, visualization

first of all, in case I comment on any mistakes while writing this, sorry, English is not my first language.

I'm a begginer with Data vizualiation with python, I have a dataframe with 115 rows, and I want to do a scatterplot with 4 quadrants and show the values in R1 (image below for reference)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dKR9.png)

At moment this is my scatterplot. It's a football player dataset so I want to plot the name of the players name in the 'R1'. Is that possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUsf.png)

Comment: provide a reproducible example and explain how the quadrants are defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate each point by making a sub-dataframe of just the players in a quadrant that you care about based on their x/y values using `plt.annotate`. So something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

##### Making a mock dataset #################################################
names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
value_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
value_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(names, value_1, value_2), columns = ['name', 'v_1', 'v_2'])
#############################################################################

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5) # sizing parameter to make the graph bigger
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(x = value_1, y = value_2, s = 100) # graph code

# Code to make a subset of data that fits the specific conditions that I want to annotate
quadrant = df[(df.v_1 > 3) & (df.v_2 > 3)].reset_index(drop = True)

# Code to annotate the above "quadrant" on the graph
for x in range(len(quadrant)):
    plt.annotate('Player: {}\nValue 1: {}\nValue 2: {}'.format(quadrant.name[x], quadrant.v_1[x], quadrant.v_2[x]),
                 (quadrant.v_1[x], quadrant.v_2[x])
```

Output graph:

[image]

If you're just working in the notebook and don't need to save the image with all the player's names, then using a "hover" feature might be a better idea. Annotating every player's name might become too busy for the graph, so just hovering over the point might work out better for you.

```py
%matplotlib widget # place this or "%matplotlib notebook" at the top of your notebook
                   # This allows you to work with matplotlib graphs in line

import mplcursors # this is the module that allows hovering features on your graph

# using the same dataframe from above
ax1 = sns.scatterplot(x = value_1, y = value_2, s = 100)
@mplcursors.cursor(ax1, hover=2).connect("add") # add the plot to the hover feature of mplcursors
def _(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_text('Player: {}\nValue 1: {}\nValue 2: {}'.format(df.name[sel.index], sel.target[0], sel.target[0])) # set the text


    # you don't need any of the below but I like to customize
    sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set(fc="lightcoral", alpha=1) # set the box color
    sel.annotation.arrow_patch.set(arrowstyle='-|>', connectionstyle='angle3', fc='black', alpha=.5) # set the arrow style
```

Example outputs from hovering:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do two (or more) scatter plots on a single figure.

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you could separate your dataset in two :

1. Points for which you don't want the name to be plotted
2. Points for which you want the name to be plotted

You can then plot the second data set and display the name.

Without any other details on your problem, it is difficult to do more. You could edit your question and add a minimal example of your data set.